# Perforce P4 Submit command line option

Tags: perforce

I would like to know if there is a way to use p4 Submit with comments contained in a comment file.
i.e p4 Submit "Comment File.txt" fileName

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-i` option to read the changelist spec (including the comment) from a file or stdin. Something like

```
mumblemumble.pl > changelistspec.txt
p4 submit -i < changelistspec.txt
```

The format of the changlelistspec.txt is the same as the file that pops up when you run `p4 submit` interactively.  Use

```
p4 submit -d
```

to view the changelistspec. Your script or whatever needs to output in that format.

Answer (score 1):

You can load the contents of the comment file into an environment variable and then pass that to the `submit` command.

```
set /p p4description=<"Comment File.txt"
p4 submit -d "%p4description%"

::you can then get rid of that environment variable...
set p4description=
```